# How to avoid duplicate output with findall in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am using following code:

```
father_child(tom, sally).
father_child(john, alfred).
father_child(george, peter).
father_child(tom, dick).
father_child(john, harry).
father_child(george, eliz).

siblings(X, Y):-  father_child(Z, X), father_child(Z, Y), dif(X,Y).
```

I can get a list of all siblings using following code but it produces duplicate output, with sibling position in set reversed. How can this be avoided:

```
?- findall((X,Y), siblings(X,Y), L).
L = [ (sally, dick), (alfred, harry), (peter, eliz), (dick, sally), (harry, alfred), (eliz, peter)].
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is, instead of using `dif/2`, to use `@</2` as a way to not only make sure they're different but in a particular order, ensuring uniqueness of the pair:

```
siblings(X, Y):-  father_child(Z, X), father_child(Z, Y), X @< Y.
```